# MQTT How to send back to client in IoT?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I am new beginner and try to create IoT network.
As I search on the Internet and see some information, 
there is a device (MQTT client), and broker (MQTT server). 
I have use node.js (masca) to setup a web server with static IP as "broker".
I have a TinkerBoard as "device", and it run bash command as publisher. 
But I meet a problem and very confuse about the architecture... all the sample code I found are one-way communication.
The broker does not send anything back to device.
Is that necessary I have to create both publisher and subscriber program in the device to allow user send command through the broker to control the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you want to receive messages on your device as well as publish them then it will have be both a subscriber and publisher.

It is perfectly normal for a single client to do both.

Comment: Yes, for example https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2019/06/iot-control-system-at-edge-mimic-mqtt.html